# magento 2 downlodable product when upload pdf display pop up "Attention true"

Tags: magento2

in Magento 2 i want to upload a book in pdf in Downloadable Type product.
My pdf size are 11.5 MB. When i upload this pdf a pop up are displayed 
like -- "Attention true".

[image]

and also when upload smaller size pdf its uploaded normally.

Question:- Why this error are display dose Magento 2 have size limit on uploaded file...?

Answer (score 2):

There is no Default setting in Admin:

You have to update your php.ini settings:

> /etc/php/  your_php_version directory  /apache2/php.ini

Upload below attributes.

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

After update:
sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i made all change as your ask.
But still not upload my pdf...!

Comment: I have tested and suggest you to do the same. Are you on the local server?

Comment: I face the same issue as you mentioned. And did the above changes and it is resolved. Yes you can add php bin/magetno cache:clean after sudo service apache2 restart